# Solving a reduce/reduce conflict

Tags: grammar, bison, yacc

If I have a grammar where a certain expression can match two productions, I will obviously have a reduce/reduce conflict with yacc. Specifically, say I have two productions (FirstProduction and SecondProduction) where both of them could be `TOKEN END`.

Then yacc will not be able to know what to reduce `TOKEN END` to (FirstProduction or SecondProduction). However, I want to make it so that yacc prioritises `FirstProduction` in this situation. How can I achieve that?

Note that both `FirstProduction` and `SecondProduction` could be a great deal of things and that `Body` is the only place in the grammar where these conflict.

Also, I do know that in these situations, yacc will choose the first production that was declared in the grammar. However, I want to avoid having any reduce/reduce warnings.

Comment: You mean `Body: FirstProduction | SecondProduction`, right?

Comment: I edited it to reflect that Body can be a list of FirstProductions or a list of SecondProductions (a list of 0 or more instances of First or Second productions). This way, I did not mean what you said, but instead what I said (albeit edited), for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refactor the grammar to not allow the second list to start with something that could be part of the first list:

```
Body: FirstProductionList SecondProductionList
    | FirstProductionList
    ;

FirstProductionList: FirstProductionList FirstProduction
                   | /* empty */
                   ;

SecondProductionList: SecondProductionList SecondProduction
                    | NonFirstProduction
                    ;
```

`NonFirstProduction` is any production that is unique to `SecondProduction`, and marks the transition from reducing `FirstProdution`s to `SecondProduction`s

Answer (score 1):

Bison has no way to explicitly mark one production as preferred over another; the only such mechanism is precedence relations, which resolve shift/reduce conflicts. As you say, the file order provides an implicit priority. You can suppress the warning with an `%expect` declaration; unfortunately, that only lets you tell bison how many conflicts to expect, and not which conflicts.